# How to calculate the expectation of sample variance?

Tags: statistics

Assuming $$x_1,...,x_T$$ are i.i.d with $$E(x_t)=μ$$ and $$var(x_t)=\sigma^2$$, and sample moments $$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{T} \Sigma_1^T x_t$$ and $$\hat{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{T} \Sigma_1^T (x_t-\hat{\mu})^2$$

We can calculate that $$ E[\hat{\mu}] = μ $$and $$Var[\hat{\mu}] = \frac{1}{T}\sigma^2$$.

**How can we calculate $$E[\hat{\sigma^2}]? $$**
The answer is $$\frac{T-1}{T} \sigma^2$$ but I'm now sure how to get there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $x_t$ iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$,
$$E[\hat\sigma^2]=E\left[\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T(x_t-\hat\mu)^2\right]\\
=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^TE\left[(x_t-\hat\mu)^2\right]\\
=E\left[(x_1-\hat\mu)^2\right]\\
=\text{Var}(x_1-\hat\mu)\\
=\text{Var}(x_1)+\text{Var}(\hat\mu)-2\text{Cov}(x_1,\hat\mu)\\
=\text{Var}(x_1)+\text{Var}(\hat\mu)-2\text{Cov}\left(x_1,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^Tx_t\right)\\
=\text{Var}(x_1)+\underbrace{\text{Var}(\hat\mu)}_{=\sigma^2/T}-\frac{2}{T}\left(\underbrace{\text{Var}(x_1)}_{=\sigma^2}+\sum_{t=2}^T\underbrace{\text{Cov}(x_1,x_t)}_{=0}\right)\\
=\frac{T-1}{T}\sigma^2
$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the second to last equation? How to expand the Cov term? Where does var(mu^hat) go?

Comment: We have $\text{Cov}(x_1,\hat\mu)=\text{Cov}\left(x_1,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_t\right).$ From here, I used the property of covariances that $\text{Cov}(X,aY+bZ)=a\text{Cov}(X,Y)+b\text{Cov}(X,Z).$ Lmk if that makes sense.

Comment: And $\text{Var}(\hat \mu)=\sigma^2/T$

Comment: added some details

Comment: Yes it makes sense thank you!

Comment: No prob! Pls upvote if you found it helpful